# Alexa Skill: Interaction model is not being updated during test

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am developing a Alexa Skill and I have an `Intent` named `NewAppointmentIntent` which originally had 7 slots. 
I have added a new `Slot` yesterday named `Doctor` and successfully built the Skill.

When I invoke that intent, it still have 7 Slots and not 8. The `Doctor` Slot does not appears in the **request** and **responses** outputs.

The Intent in images:

[image]

[image]

The `output` when invocing the `Intent`, where slot `Doctor` expected in `slots` attribute:

```html
"request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.9529849e-190d-4278-95a8-3702b3ee4d1c",
  "timestamp": "2018-12-12T10:05:14Z",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "intent": {
   "name": "NewAppointmentIntent",
   "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
   "slots": {
    "Status": {
     "name": "Status",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "Comment": {
     "name": "Comment",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "ReasonForVisit": {
     "name": "ReasonForVisit",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "Time": {
     "name": "Time",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "EmergencyType": {
     "name": "EmergencyType",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "PatientNumber": {
     "name": "PatientNumber",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    },
    "Day": {
     "name": "Day",
     "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
    }
   }
  },
  "dialogState": "STARTED"
 }
```

**So I wish to know how to refresh the Skill?**

Answer (score 0):

Close the window, re-open and in your console -> Save the model -> Build the model. Then test again.

If still doesn't show, click on the JSON Editor(this will be the last option in the list of your Interaction model), then in your `NewAppointmentIntent` can you see the `Docter` slot in the `slots` array?

If not, then maybe something was broken when you created the slot. So delete the `Docter` slot and re-add it. Then again verify it in JSON editor and this should solve the problem.

Comment: I just tried all this and nothing has changed. My interaction model is up to date and contains all the slots but during the tests it still doesn't appear in the JSON

Comment: Did you see the `JSON Editor`? Also, does your `NewAppointmentIntent` has utterances that use `Docter` slot? Try adding 2-3 more utterances with this `Docter` slot to `NewAppointmentIntent`.

Comment: The `JSON File Model` is also up to date with that new slot `Doctor`. 
After doing the build as you describe above, it's still not work during test.

Comment: Ahhh. I see, maybe the problem is in `AMAZON.Number`, Your input value is in integer, say `12` or `123456789`, But `AMAZON.Number` converts `one` to `1`, `one hundred four` to `104` etc. (See docs here - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#number). For your slot type, create a custom Slot and see if it works or use `AMAZON.SearchQuery`(docs here - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery)